# CSS: Highlight current menu item

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with links in the following form, in which I am trying to highlight the current menu item. I can't seem to get it working. Please advice as to what I am doing wrong

HTML

```
<body id="home">
```

```
                <div id="topMenu">
                    <div class="nav-home" id="topMenuBlock"><a href="" id="home"><p>Home</p></a></div>
                    <div id="nav-about"><a href="" id="about"><p>About</p></a></div>
                    <div id="nav-rates"><a href="" id="rates"><p>Rates</p></a></div>
                    <div id="nav-faq"><a href="" id="faq"><p>FAQ</p></a></div>
                    <div id="nav-contact"><a href="" id="contactus"><p>Contact</p></a></div>
                    <div id="nav-careers"><a href="careers.html" id="contactus"><p>Careers</p></a></div>
                </div>

                <div id="rightTopMenu"></div>
        </div>...other stuff</body>
```

Then for the CSS I have the following:

```
#home a.nav-home{ border-bottom:2px solid white; }
```

Do the links HAVE to be in a List, or can I leave them in div's, and if so, how can I make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a little bit of a mess here.

> Do the links HAVE to be in a List, or can I leave them in div's?

They don't *have* to be, but they probably should be. There's not good reason to use the strange markup you have chosen, you should definitely consider switching to a list and `<li>` tags.

#### Problem with duplicate ids

- You have `<body id="home">` and `<a href="" id="home">`
- You also have several instances of `id="topMenuBlock"` (I see you fixed this in your edit.)

You cannot have more than one element with the same id. `id` attributes must be unique, always. Use class names instead, if anything.

You are using this selector: `#home a.nav-home {}` but it doesn't match anything. There is no `<a class="nav-home">`. You can use something like:

- `#home {}` because that's the `id` of the `<a>` element you want
- `.nav-home a {}` - Selects the `<a>` inside an element with `class="nav-home"`

Comment: I can't see the big picture, but my gut feeling is that you are going overboard adding classes and ids to every element. You usually don't need all that, and can work with something much simpler.

Comment: I ll keep that in mind and try to get rid of excess id's and such. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have the concept of ids and classes mixed up. Ids are supposed to uniquely identify HTML elements, whereas classes can be used as many times as you like.  Right now you have 6 elements with the id `#topMenuBlock`.  You should make a `.topMenuBlock` class instead.    I would also make a `#nav-home` id instead of a class since there should only be one such element on each page.

Secondly, there is no need for the `<p>` tags you have within your `<a>` tags.  In fact, it's against HTML standards to do so since anchors are inline elements and paragraphs are block-level elements.

Lastly, your CSS selector that sets the border is incorrect because the `.nav-home` div is not contained within an `<a>` element.  Use this CSS instead (assuming you change nav-home to be an id rather than a class):

```
#nav-home{ border-bottom:2px solid white; }
```

Fix these issues and then see what happens.  If you're new to HTML and CSS, I would recommend going through some tutorials, such as the ones found at http://www.w3schools.com/.

Comment: Sorry for repeating some of what you said, Madmartigan, I should have refreshed my page before posting.

Comment: It's good that you posted this, OP needs help. However, I disagree with your choice of reference. I would suggest http://htmldog.com/ for absolute beginners, and http://reference.sitepoint.com/ for more advanced stuff and reference. w3schools is notorious for being terrible, there are tons of questions here from mixed up newbies because they learned from that site. More good references here: http://w3fools.com/#what-should-be-done

Comment: Actually in HTML5, it's OK to have `<p>` as a child of `<a>`, but it's besides the point because the markup in the post should be changed. I'm sharing that info because it's rather new to me, you can now wrap a whole section of content in `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class identifier should be in the `<a />` tag

You have

```
<div class="nav-home" id="topMenuBlock"><a href="" id="home"><p>Home</p></a></div>
```

but you want

```
<div class="something" id="topMenuBlock"><a class = "nav-home" href="" id="home"><p>Home</p></a></div>
```

Modify your CSS class accordingly.